# What are the differences between dockerfile and stackbrew users on docker hub

Tags: docker

There are two users [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/u/dockerfile/) and [stackbrew](https://hub.docker.com/u/stackbrew/) on docker hub site. Both of them have a lot of "standard" repositories, for example mongodb repository.

- What are the differences between them?
- Which of them is more "official"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stackbrew is the official images project, all images owned by the stackbrew user are curated and verified by people at Docker. There's more info on the project available on our [Github repo](https://github.com/dotcloud/stackbrew).

The dockerfile namespace is not official or supervised by us. It does have some repositories that are not (yet) available as an official image, but it's something we're looking to fix as time goes on.

Also note that any image under the stackbrew/ namespace mirrors the official image of the same name, i.e. `stackbrew/ubuntu` is the same as `ubuntu`, `stackbrew/ruby` the same as `ruby`; etc.

Comment: and "dockerfile" repositories have associated Dockerfiles :)

Comment: True, dockerfile uses the automated build system, stackbrew doesn't for technical reasons (if we did ubuntu:14.04, ubuntu:trusty and ubuntu:latest would be 3 separate images with their own layers, and noone that's ever done `docker pull ubuntu` wants that :)).

It's clearly something we need to improve though!